Help for getting toddler to sleep
Our daughter who is 2 and in her own room now has started to play up when going to bed, we bath her, have relaxed environment, tell a story and she is tired but when I cuddle her now she has started rolling around and getting up, playing up. I would like to leave her but she cries and my wife doesn’t want to leave her so stuck a little bit as it’s tough, but I feel she is testing us but she is definitely tired,wondered if there was anything we can do? Thankyou

How recent is the change that your daughter is sleeping in her own room? Did anything else change in her bedtime routine, or only the room where her bed is located?

She has been in her room for a while, been in her bed for months and likes her bed she just seems to be playing up, even though tired! We have tried to take her up early so not overtired and also later incase no tired, it’s been worse this week but she rolls over and starts jibbering and chatting and sitting up, try to lay her back down multiple times and sssh her but it’s like she is playing!

There are multiple possible explanations for her behavior and just as many different ways to deal with it.
On the one hand, she is at an age where children really start to test boundaries. You it can be that she is really trying to see what reaction she gets by not doing what you want her to do (which is, going to sleep).
If that is the underlying reason, then it will not help to keep giving her attention in response to her "misbehavior". It is better to make sure her room is safe that she cannot hurt herself when messing around in her bed, including by falling/climbing out of the bed. Do not engage with her when she starts playing and leave the room as you would normally at the end of the bedtime routine. Also, do not respond immediately if she starts crying the moment the door closes behind you. The lesson to learn here is that these behaviors will not be rewarded by attention. If the crying starts later or persists, do check on her to see if its just attention she wants or if there is something different the matter.
Another possibility is that she has had a regression in her sleeping habits and has "forgotten" how to fall asleep when alone and by herself. Some signs of this would be that it is easier for her to fall asleep in your arms or when you are clearly present. The remedy here is a sleep-training program where you gradually teach her again to go to sleep without your presence.

Hi Thankyou yeh she has hardly ever fallen asleep on her own, very stubborn and usually get her to sleep by laying next to her! So will try all the above and see, thankyou

What we did for our 1yr old was the 10 minute method:

We'd put him to bed and his screaming started and would not end (we gave it an hour once).
Wait 10 minutes.
We go to his room, place him back in sleeping position, give him a gentle stroke and leave again. This whole bit we don't speak.
Repeat.

Ten minutes because the child needs to learn we're not instantly back. Its time to sleep, not for interactions. Also: sometimes he just had to "power off", let the excess steam off.
We placed him back in sleeping position to indicate what we're expecting: time to sleep.
We gently stroke as a sign of care. Its not that we don't love you, its just that you need to sleep now. For that same reason we didnt talk to him, its not time for social interaction now.
When we started this, it took 60 minutes (6 trips). This was very difficult, staying calm is a challenge, but very important. The second day it was 40 minutes, then 20 minutes and now we rarely need to interact and if we do, most of the time something is actually going on.

There are no universal prescriptions, and it is up to the parents to decide. Possible options that readily come to mind:

Leaving the child alone and letting them scream is a possible option - obviously many children would not willingly agree to abandon the comfort given by the presence of parent. But it is important not to overdo being tough - it is one thing when a child cries for a few minutes and falls asleep, but if they keep screaming for a quarter or half a hour, one needs a more subtle approach.
Not staying in bed can be enforced by "punitive" actions - like taking away some toys, turning off the light, etc. (whether you call them "punishment" or "sanctions" is a matter of taste)
On the "carrot" side of the educational "carrot and stick" one could leave the light on (or leave the light in the adjacent corridor, or turning a small table-lamp, night light) - indeed, most children feel uneasy in darkness, even if they do not realize/verbalize it as an outright fear.
Staying with the child on the condition that they stay in bed - a parent can occupy themselves by reading a book or using their smartphone.
Reading a story while already in bed or discussing the events of the day.

Important factor is transforming the evening routine into a habit by repeating it over and over for weeks and months, and perhaps gradually withdrawing those of the "special privileges", which are most difficult for the parents. (E.g., I do not see any harm in letting a child to fall sleep with a nightlight, but staying by their side for hours or letting them fall asleep in the parent's bed is something that would have to be eventually discontinued.)
